# Doctrine n+1 issue with ManyToMany relation despite using EAGER loading

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I am testing out API Platform and I am running into n+1 issues with Doctrine. I have an entity called Car which has a ManyToMany relation with Driver. I have not done anything custom, I am just testing API Platform in it's default (apparently) state.

Car entity:

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Driver::class, mappedBy: 'car', fetch: 'EAGER')]
#[ORM\JoinTable(name: "cars_to_drivers")]
    private Collection $drivers;
```

Driver entity:

```
 #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Car::class, mappedBy: 'driver', fetch: 'EAGER')]
 #[ORM\JoinTable(name: "cars_to_drivers")]
        private Collection $cars;
```

When I hit the GET endpoint to get the cars (30 per page), I can see in the Doctrine profiler that there are 32 queries being run: one to get the count, one to get all the cars, and one query per car to get the drivers for that car. Doctrine seems to insist on making these extra queries despite me forcing eager loading. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Why not set fetch to 'EXTRA_LAZY' !?

Comment: I never really had much luck with the fetch parameter.  Always seemed a bit hit or miss.  Plus it is basically a global setting which you may not always want.  If you make a custom query and explicitly select both Car and Driver then everything loads in one gulp.  It's an extra step but almost guaranteed to work every time.

Comment: @Francisco it does the same thing with extra lazy.

Comment: @Cerad I bypass Doctrine with raw SQL very often, and that is what I am considering doing here, yet again. I seem to find myself working around Doctrine more than working with it.

Comment: Not SQL but DQL.  DQLs query builder has an addSelect(car.drivers) should pull in the driver entities eagerly.  You still get your entities.  Oops. Looks like someone beat me to it.  But yes DQL and the entire entity mapping thing does have limits.  But most of the time is does beat the alternatives.  Especially when updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to revert to raw sql to accomplish N+1 solutions. As Cerad suggested, you need to make a custom query, but he didn't mean SQL. This can be done in DQL or with the QueryBuilder.

This is the simplest example. This will remove the N+1 problem when selecting cars with related drivers.

```php
// CarRepository.php
    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('car')
            ->innerJoin('car.drivers', 'drivers')
            ->addSelect('drivers');
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
// ...
```

Then you use the `getCars` query instead of whatever you are currently using. Of course you can filter or limit the query (for pagination).